# Send Multiple push notification from php server to ios Devices

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

i am working on a app where there is need to send bulk push notification from the Php server to ios devices . Is there any way to send multiple push notification from Php server to all devices without using any Loop. *because this loop process reduce response time to client from the server

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [ApnsPHP](https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP), then there is a way. This code is from his `sample_push_many.php` file. First you have to add all the recepients

```
$push->connect();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $message = new ApnsPHP_Message($i == 5 ? INVALID_TOKEN : VALID_TOKEN);
    $message->setCustomIdentifier(sprintf("Message-Badge-%03d", $i));
    $message->setBadge($i);
    $push->add($message);
}
$push->send();
```